# How to change the URL of <select>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my code:

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="sortby">
<option value="1">Option 1 </option>
<option value="2">Option 2 </option>
<option value="3">Option 3 </option>
<option value="4">Option 4 </option>
<option value="5">Option 5 </option>
</select>
```

Now, when i submit this post, I want the url to be like this:

```
?page=".$page."&tag=".$tag."&sortby=SELECTEDVALUEHERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are using php... If so, use this code.
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the current page and you can edit the tag as needed.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value=<?php echo '"' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '"'>
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="yourTag">
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="sortby">
<option value="1">Option 1 </option>
<option value="2">Option 2 </option>
<option value="3">Option 3 </option>
<option value="4">Option 4 </option>
<option value="5">Option 5 </option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**:
The above code is giving this url: `/index.php?page=index.php&tag=yourTag&sortby=3`

Answer (score 1):

It is the solution.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="sortby">
<option value="1">Option 1 </option>
<option value="2">Option 2 </option>
<option value="3">Option 3 </option>
<option value="4">Option 4 </option>
<option value="5">Option 5 </option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="<?php echo $tag ?>" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in form action use,

```
yourphpfile.php?page=".$page."&tag=".$tag."
```